# static property of SignalR hub has more than 1 instance

Tags: c#, static, signalr, instance, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR hub with a static property containing the subscriptions.

Here's an example:

```
[HubName("MyHub")]
public class MyHub: Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
{
    private static readonly Subscriptions subscriptions = new Subscriptions();
    // ...
}
```

The `Subscriptions` class contains a thread-safe list, and a random GUID as property for testing purposes:

```
public class Subscriptions
{
    public string GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    // ...
}
```

Since the `Subscriptions` is a static property of the hub, you expect it to only exist as one instance. However, when I add a subscription, the GUID property differs from when I try to remove a subscription.
So that means that the static property somehow has multiple instances?

So, how could if fix this? How could I force the static to only exist in one instance?

Or what would be a better alternative for saving "states" in a SignalR hub?

Comment: How do you add and remove subscriptions? GUID is a field or property? In your code it's a field and you call it property, probably you have a get only property with `=>` syntax?

Comment: The GUID is a simple field. And the add and remove is used with a lock to make it thread-safe.